# strtotime() ads a minute of month change

Tags: php

I am adding a month to a string fromated date with this code:

```
$str ="2017-01-29 14:22:57";
$effectiveDate = strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($str));
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d h:m:s',strtotime($str));
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d h:m:s',$effectiveDate);
```

The output is:

```
2017-01-29 02:01:57
2017-03-01 02:03:57
```

I am wondering, why is there a minute change? It seems that every month there is a 1 min change.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for `m` => *m  Numeric representation of a **month**, with leading zeros  01 through 12* - You want `i` for **minutes**. Instead of `h:m:s` do `h:i:s` that's why.

Comment: Just an hint: You can also do `$effectiveDate = strtotime("$str +1 months");`

Comment: Also helpfull: http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just pop this in as a community wiki; I don't want rep for this, nor should there be any made from it.

From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`m` => *m   Numeric representation of a **month**, with leading zeros   01 through 12*

You want `i` for **minutes**. Instead of `h:m:s` do `h:i:s` that's why.

Comment: @sanjihan Plus, you may have thought that the `m` stood for "minutes", which in a sense is perfectly logical.

Answer (score 1):

You're formatting as hour:month:seconds, to have the timestamp you'll want to do:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $effectiveDate);
```

See the [date documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information.